# Header is not working generated excel file...?

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-poi

i am trying to set header but it is not working in generated excel file and data is printing on generated excel but header is not working kindly suggest i have this code.

```
public class Csv {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("My Sheet");
        //HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Excel Sheet");
        XSSFRow rowhead;
        rowhead = sheet.createRow(0);
        rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("Designation");
        rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Title");
        rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Domain");
        rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Name");


        try {

            // To connect to mongodb server
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

            // Now connect to your databases
            DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mytest");
            System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

            DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("myCollection");
            System.out.println("Collection mycol selected successfully");

            DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
            int i = 0;
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                DBObject o = cursor.next();
                //String fname = (String) o.get("Employee ID") ; 
                String lname = (String) o.get("Designation");
                String sid = (String) o.get("Title");
                String prg = (String) o.get("Domain");
                String lvl = (String) o.get("Name");


                Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue(lname);
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(sid);
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(prg);
                row.createCell(3).setCellValue(lvl);
                i++;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `int i = 0;` in code to `int i = 1;`

Since you already used `row(0)` as header, next row should start from `row(1)`.